# find a bug when try to add another UIImageView on top of the first one

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to cross-fade images when the user choose a new image filter.

So I created the secondImageView on top of the first one,and animate the alpha of the top view to show or hide the bottom view.

here is my showSecondImageView() function：

```
    func showSecondImageView() {
        view.addSubview(secondImageView)

        secondImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        let bottomConstraint = secondImageView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.topAnchor)
        let leftConstraint = secondImageView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.leftAnchor)
        let rightConstraint = secondImageView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.rightAnchor)
        let heightConstraint = secondImageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.heightAnchor)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([bottomConstraint,leftConstraint,rightConstraint,heightConstraint])

        view.layoutIfNeeded()


        self.secondImageView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
            self.secondImageView.alpha = 1.0
    }

}
```

the Output:

```
    2016-02-14 23:50:17.444 Filterer[3484:344297] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c33c80 UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0.leading == UIView:0x7fdf58c22480.leading>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c0ff70 UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0.trailing == UIView:0x7fdf58c22480.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c1d7d0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fdf58c22480]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fdf58c19270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c1d820 H:[UIView:0x7fdf58c22480]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fdf58c19270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58f30850 H:[UIImageView:0x7fdf58f30440(600)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c5e350 UIImageView:0x7fdf58f30440.left == UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0.left>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c79c40 UIImageView:0x7fdf58f30440.right == UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0.right>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c32190 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fdf58c19270(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58f30850 H:[UIImageView:0x7fdf58f30440(600)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-14 23:50:17.446 Filterer[3484:344297] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fdf58c165e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fdf58c0fde0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fdf58c2eb70 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fdf58c0fde0.bottom == UIView:0x7fdf58c19270.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c35fc0 V:[UIButton:0x7fdf58c35d20'New Photo'(45)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c31740 V:[UIStackView:0x7fdf58c30420]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fdf58c22480 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c318a0 V:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7fdf58c30420]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fdf58c22480 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c0ffc0 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fdf58c19270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c26f70 V:[UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fdf58c22480]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c26fc0 V:[UIView:0x7fdf58c22480]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fdf58c0fde0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58f30ab0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fdf58f30440(555)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c74640 UIImageView:0x7fdf58f30440.height == UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c323e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fdf58c30420.top == UIButton:0x7fdf58c35d20'New Photo'.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c3dd40 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIButton:0x7fdf58c35d20'New Photo']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fdf58c30420 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c3fe60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fdf58c19270(667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c35fc0 V:[UIButton:0x7fdf58c35d20'New Photo'(45)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-14 23:50:17.461 Filterer[3484:344297] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fdf58c165e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fdf58c0fde0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fdf58c2eb70 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fdf58c0fde0.bottom == UIView:0x7fdf58c19270.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c17050 V:[UIButton:0x7fdf58c16940'Edit'(45)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c31740 V:[UIStackView:0x7fdf58c30420]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fdf58c22480 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c318a0 V:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7fdf58c30420]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fdf58c22480 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c0ffc0 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fdf58c19270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c26f70 V:[UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fdf58c22480]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c26fc0 V:[UIView:0x7fdf58c22480]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fdf58c0fde0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58f30ab0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fdf58f30440(555)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c74640 UIImageView:0x7fdf58f30440.height == UIImageView:0x7fdf58c30ed0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c3fa40 'UISV-alignment' UIButton:0x7fdf58c35d20'New Photo'.bottom == UIButton:0x7fdf58c16940'Edit'.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c404d0 'UISV-alignment' UIButton:0x7fdf58c35d20'New Photo'.top == UIButton:0x7fdf58c16940'Edit'.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c323e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fdf58c30420.top == UIButton:0x7fdf58c35d20'New Photo'.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c3dd40 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIButton:0x7fdf58c35d20'New Photo']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fdf58c30420 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c3fe60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fdf58c19270(667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fdf58c17050 V:[UIButton:0x7fdf58c16940'Edit'(45)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

[image]

[image]

the first picture is the bug one,the second picture is what I want it look like,how to fix it ?

[image]

Comment: "the Output says "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"" - It says more than that. A _lot_ more. Show the entire message, please. Also please describe the view hierarchy more accurately and completely.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the view hierarchy and the entire message:-)

Comment: It looks to me as if you are in much deeper doodoo than you have previously admitted. You are telling me you never got those messages _before_ you added the second image view?

Comment: Why don't you just change the image view's image and then use `UIView.transitionWithView:`? It'll be easier and save you some performance too (in the long run).

Comment: Yes,I never got those messages before. And I just had look at the constraints of the bottomMenu,I found that the topAnchor of bottomMenu constraint to imageView. Is it possible that the imageView changed when the secondImageView was added, which cause the change of the bottomMenu? @matt

Answer (score 0):

For exactly the same problem you have! I went with the UIView.transitionWithView option mentioned above:

```
  UIView.transitionWithView( myImageView,
        duration: 0.4,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
        animations: { self.myImageView.image = toShow},
        completion: { completed in
            //do nothing here})
```

Where the variable "toShow" is the new image.  This avoids the need to manage the subview.